Check if greatest rolling change is less than a specific number in dataframe
I have a dataframe of a time series of stock prices and need to see at any point in time if the change (whether it be pct_change(1), pct_change(2), ... , pct_change(7) is less than 20%).
The logic I am trying to emulate is trying to capture at any point in time starting from 1 week ago for each respective date whether there was a -20% move within previous 7 days.
So far I am basically looping through every single row, getting the list of prices for .iloc[i-7:i] and comparing the highest price and lowest price within each interval for each row... but there must be some better way?
e.g. for below data
Date          Price    -20 Pct Move Trigger
2024-01-11    2569.0   
2024-01-12    2745.0
2024-01-15    3100.0
2024-01-16    3595.0
2024-01-17    4295.0
2024-01-18    3595.0
2024-01-19    3280.0    True
2024-01-22    3505.0
2024-01-23    3945.0
2024-01-24    4075.0
2024-01-25    3990.0
2024-01-26    3855.0
2024-01-29    3740.0
2024-01-30    3590.0
2024-01-31    3620.0
2024-02-01    3810.0
2024-02-02    4150.0
2024-02-05    3915.0
2024-02-06    3855.0


Please provide a reproducible example.

You do not need to loop. Just compute the percentages and check which ones are smaller than 20
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=60, freq='D')
prices = np.random.lognormal(mean=0, sigma=0.1, size=len(dates)) * 100

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Price': prices})

df['Max7'] = df['Price'].rolling(window=7, min_periods=1).max()
df['Min7'] = df['Price'].rolling(window=7, min_periods=1).min()

df['PctChange7'] = (df['Min7'] - df['Max7']) / df['Max7'] * 100

df['-20PctMove'] = df['PctChange7'] <= -20

print("DataFrame with 7-day window analysis:")
print(df.head(15))

which gives

DataFrame with 7-day window analysis:
         Date       Price        Max7        Min7  PctChange7  -20PctMove
0  2023-01-01  105.092572  105.092572  105.092572    0.000000       False
1  2023-01-02   98.626872  105.092572   98.626872   -6.152386       False
2  2023-01-03  106.691238  106.691238   98.626872   -7.558603       False
3  2023-01-04  116.451301  116.451301   98.626872  -15.306338       False
4  2023-01-05   97.685667  116.451301   97.685667  -16.114576       False
5  2023-01-06   97.685828  116.451301   97.685667  -16.114576       False
6  2023-01-07  117.107401  117.107401   97.685667  -16.584548       False
7  2023-01-08  107.976505  117.107401   97.685667  -16.584548       False
8  2023-01-09   95.413755  117.107401   95.413755  -18.524573       False
9  2023-01-10  105.575485  117.107401   95.413755  -18.524573       False
10 2023-01-11   95.471561  117.107401   95.413755  -18.524573       False
11 2023-01-12   95.449490  117.107401   95.413755  -18.524573       False
12 2023-01-13  102.449133  117.107401   95.413755  -18.524573       False
13 2023-01-14   82.586164  107.976505   82.586164  -23.514691        True
14 2023-01-15   84.156520  105.575485   82.586164  -21.775245        True


Thank you very much this is indeed on close to what I need - guess I do need to add another line so to distinguish the trend increasing since even if price was increasing the max - min would still trigger this.
e.g. if data looked like 2023-01-08 and 2023-01-14  swapped instead where max and min values were swapped would still trigger this?

I think looping through last 7 rows might be resource intensive. I tried looping over a list. I am not 100% sure if this would be faster but you can give it a try:
closingprices=stock_data['Close'].tolist()
vals=[]
for ind,price in enumerate(closingprices):
  flags=0
  
  for x in reversed(range(0,7)):
    if (ind-x) <0 :
      
      
      print("NA")
    else:
      ablt=(ind-x)
      drop=price/closingprices[ablt]
      
      
      if drop<0.80:
        flags+=1
        
        
      else:
        
        pass
  if flags>0:
    vals.append(1)  
  else:
    vals.append(0)

stock_data['flag']=vals
      
      
    
   
    
   

